# Angular MaterializeCSS FormArray Selector

Tags: javascript, angular, materialize

I'm having problems with a form that working on.

I'm using MaterializeCSS with Angular and in order to make sure the `select` will be properly initiated i'm using the following method:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
   const selArray = this.select.toArray();
   selArray.forEach(el => {
      M.FormSelect.init(el.nativeElement);
   });
}
```

That's working fine, my problem is that I'm using **FormArray** and when I create a new `FormControl` dynamically, the `select` doesn't work. It's like it's not initialized.
I added the code above inside my `addResident()` method and it doesn't work but if I have to add again, then it works.

Here is video of the error:
https://youtu.be/v1CHkmJtzCo

Here is the code:

```
@ViewChildren('select') select: QueryList<ElementRef>;

ngAfterViewInit() {
        const selArray = this.select.toArray();
        selArray.forEach(el => {
            M.FormSelect.init(el.nativeElement);
        });
        const dpArray = this.datePicker.toArray();
        dpArray.forEach(element => {
            M.Datepicker.init(element.nativeElement);
        });
    }
```

```
addResident() {
   (this.hostForm.get('residents') as FormArray).push(
       new FormGroup({
           firstName: new FormControl(''),
           lastName: new FormControl(''),
           birthDate: new FormControl(''),
           action: new FormControl('Insert'),
           residentID: new FormControl(0),
           relationship: new FormControl('')
       })
   );
   const selArray = this.select.toArray();
   selArray.forEach(el => {
       M.FormSelect.init(el.nativeElement);
   });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use [Angular Material](https://material.angular.io/) to avoid problems with MaterializeCSS.

**https://material.angular.io/**

> Material Design components for Angular

Angular Material: [Forms](https://material.angular.io/components/categories/forms)

Angular Material: [Form-Field](https://material.angular.io/components/form-field/overview)

Have a look at the [Form-Field examples](https://material.angular.io/components/form-field/examples):

```
<div class="example-container">
  <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput placeholder="Input">
  </mat-form-field>

  <mat-form-field>
    <textarea matInput placeholder="Textarea"></textarea>
  </mat-form-field>

  <mat-form-field>
    <mat-select placeholder="Select">
      <mat-option value="option">Option</mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey thanks but at this point restarting the entire project will be crazy. I worked around the issue creating a second method to initiate everything. Thank you!